# read json graph networkx file

Tags: python, json, networkx

I'm writing a networkx graph by using this Python function:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
def save_json(filename,graph):
    g = graph
    g_json = json_graph.node_link_data(g)
    json.dump(g_json,open(filename,'w'),indent=2)
```

and was trying to load the graph using:

```
def read_json_file(filename):
    graph = json_graph.loads(open(filename))
    return graph
```

where the read function was taken from [here](http://nullege.com/codes/search/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.load).

My problem is that is gives me the error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'`

which makes sense, since from the networkx documentation there is no [load method](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html#module-networkx.readwrite.json_graph).

So, my question is how to I load a json file that contains a networkx graph?

Comment: `json_graph.loads` or `json_graph.load`?

Comment: Need  `import json` statement too...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

given what the [official docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html) say, I think you are looking for something like

```
def read_json_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        js_graph = json.load(f)
    return json_graph.node_link_graph(js_graph)
```

i.e. since the json file is written using `json.dump`, then use `json.load` to read the contents back.

Then create the graph from the loaded dictionary.

Note: I have never used the `json_graph` package so I ignore what the correct options may be in order to recreate your specific type of graph. You might want to go through them in the docs, there appear to be quite a few.

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to improve this by changing `js_graph = json.load(f)` with `js_graph = json.loads(json.load(f))`. The `node_link_graph` function takes dict object. `json.load(f)` would only return the string version of the graph, so we have to convert it back to dict.

Comment: `json.load` converts the input file contents according to [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table). As you can see, an object is returned as a dictionary already

Comment: `node_link_graph` is now directly under the main networkx package, so you can do `nx.node_link_graph(js_graph)`.