# I am on the edge of the networkx I need more color than one

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, bokeh

The example that Bokeh and networkx have on their documentation is working. I don't know the data they are using so I am using the "Karate club" data that I found and displayed below. I cannot assume this is the same data.
I read the data from a json file.

```
import networkx as nx
import json

from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.models import Circle, MultiLine
hv.extension('bokeh')

def read_json_file(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            js_graph = json.load(f)
        return json_graph.node_link_graph(js_graph)

G = read_json_file('/Users/Desktop/KCnet.json')

lst_big_nodes = []
i = 0
for lst in list(nx.connected_components(G)):
        if len(lst) > 7:  # if this connected then all nodes same color
            lst_big_nodes = lst

nd_attrs = {}
edge_attrs = {}

for nd, _ in G.nodes(data=True):
        if nd in lst_big_nodes:
            nd_attrs[nd] = '#f44171'
        else:
            nd_attrs[nd] = '#4286f4'
```

nx.set_node_attributes(G, nd_attrs, "g_color")

IN_LIST, NOT_IN_LIST = "red", "gray"
   for start_node,end_node, _ in G.edges(data=True):
            if start_node in lst_big_nodes: # or end_node in lst_big_nodes:
                edge_color = IN_LIST
            else:
                edge_color = NOT_IN_LIST
            edge_attrs[(start_node, end_node)] = edge_color

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_attrs, "edge_color")

plot = figure(title="Netwkx", plot_width=1000 ,plot_height=800,  
x_range=(-1, 1), y_range=(-1, 1),
                  tools="pan,wheel_zoom,reset", toolbar_location="above")


graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=1, center=(0, 0))
line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1)
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=8, fill_color="g_color")
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="edge_attrs", 
line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1)
plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

plot.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
plot.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

output_file("interactive_graphs.html")
show(plot)
```

I get the error:

nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_attrs, "edge_color")

for (u, v, key), value in values.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I did try a lot of different vanilla flavors around with no working code for the edge color. I am missing something and I don't see it.
Thank you for your help.

the function read_json_file is from [read json graph networkx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665042/read-json-graph-networkx-file)

[Bokeh networkx doc:](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html)

This is the data set from "Karate club"

```
    {"nodes":
[
{"color": 1, "name": "Mr Hi", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 2", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 3", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 4", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 5", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 6", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 7", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 8", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 9", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 10", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 11", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 12", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 13", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 14", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 15", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 16", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 17", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 18", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 19", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 20", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 21", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 22", "faction": 1},
{"color": 1, "name": " 23", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 24", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 25", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 26", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 27", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 28", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 29", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 30", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 31", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 32", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": " 33", "faction": 2},
{"color": 1, "name": "John A", "faction": 2}
],
"links":[
{"source": 0, "target": 1, "weight": 4, "id": "e1"},
{"source": 0, "target": 2, "weight": 5, "id": "e2"},
{"source": 0, "target": 3, "weight": 3, "id": "e3"},
{"source": 0, "target": 4, "weight": 3, "id": "e4"},
{"source": 0, "target": 5, "weight": 3, "id": "e5"},
{"source": 0, "target": 6, "weight": 3, "id": "e6"},
{"source": 0, "target": 7, "weight": 2, "id": "e7"},
{"source": 0, "target": 8, "weight": 2, "id": "e8"},
{"source": 0, "target": 10, "weight": 2, "id": "e9"},
{"source": 0, "target": 11, "weight": 3, "id": "e10"},
{"source": 0, "target": 12, "weight": 1, "id": "e11"},
{"source": 0, "target": 13, "weight": 3, "id": "e12"},
{"source": 0, "target": 17, "weight": 2, "id": "e13"},
{"source": 0, "target": 19, "weight": 2, "id": "e14"},
{"source": 0, "target": 21, "weight": 2, "id": "e15"},
{"source": 0, "target": 31, "weight": 2, "id": "e16"},
{"source": 1, "target": 2, "weight": 6, "id": "e17"},
{"source": 1, "target": 3, "weight": 3, "id": "e18"},
{"source": 1, "target": 7, "weight": 4, "id": "e19"},
{"source": 1, "target": 13, "weight": 5, "id": "e20"},
{"source": 1, "target": 17, "weight": 1, "id": "e21"},
{"source": 1, "target": 19, "weight": 2, "id": "e22"},
{"source": 1, "target": 21, "weight": 2, "id": "e23"},
{"source": 1, "target": 30, "weight": 2, "id": "e24"},
{"source": 2, "target": 3, "weight": 3, "id": "e25"},
{"source": 2, "target": 7, "weight": 4, "id": "e26"},
{"source": 2, "target": 8, "weight": 5, "id": "e27"},
{"source": 2, "target": 9, "weight": 1, "id": "e28"},
{"source": 2, "target": 13, "weight": 3, "id": "e29"},
{"source": 2, "target": 27, "weight": 2, "id": "e30"},
{"source": 2, "target": 28, "weight": 2, "id": "e31"},
{"source": 2, "target": 32, "weight": 2, "id": "e32"},
{"source": 3, "target": 7, "weight": 3, "id": "e33"},
{"source": 3, "target": 12, "weight": 3, "id": "e34"},
{"source": 3, "target": 13, "weight": 3, "id": "e35"},
{"source": 4, "target": 6, "weight": 2, "id": "e36"},
{"source": 4, "target": 10, "weight": 3, "id": "e37"},
{"source": 5, "target": 6, "weight": 5, "id": "e38"},
{"source": 5, "target": 10, "weight": 3, "id": "e39"},
{"source": 5, "target": 16, "weight": 3, "id": "e40"},
{"source": 6, "target": 16, "weight": 3, "id": "e41"},
{"source": 8, "target": 30, "weight": 3, "id": "e42"},
{"source": 8, "target": 32, "weight": 3, "id": "e43"},
{"source": 8, "target": 33, "weight": 4, "id": "e44"},
{"source": 9, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e45"},
{"source": 13, "target": 33, "weight": 3, "id": "e46"},
{"source": 14, "target": 32, "weight": 3, "id": "e47"},
{"source": 14, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e48"},
{"source": 15, "target": 32, "weight": 3, "id": "e49"},
{"source": 15, "target": 33, "weight": 4, "id": "e50"},
{"source": 18, "target": 32, "weight": 1, "id": "e51"},
{"source": 18, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e52"},
{"source": 19, "target": 33, "weight": 1, "id": "e53"},
{"source": 20, "target": 32, "weight": 3, "id": "e54"},
{"source": 20, "target": 33, "weight": 1, "id": "e55"},
{"source": 22, "target": 32, "weight": 2, "id": "e56"},
{"source": 22, "target": 33, "weight": 3, "id": "e57"},
{"source": 23, "target": 25, "weight": 5, "id": "e58"},
{"source": 23, "target": 27, "weight": 4, "id": "e59"},
{"source": 23, "target": 29, "weight": 3, "id": "e60"},
{"source": 23, "target": 32, "weight": 5, "id": "e61"},
{"source": 23, "target": 33, "weight": 4, "id": "e62"},
{"source": 24, "target": 25, "weight": 2, "id": "e63"},
{"source": 24, "target": 27, "weight": 3, "id": "e64"},
{"source": 24, "target": 31, "weight": 2, "id": "e65"},
{"source": 25, "target": 31, "weight": 7, "id": "e66"},
{"source": 26, "target": 29, "weight": 4, "id": "e67"},
{"source": 26, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e68"},
{"source": 27, "target": 33, "weight": 4, "id": "e69"},
{"source": 28, "target": 31, "weight": 2, "id": "e70"},
{"source": 28, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e71"},
{"source": 29, "target": 32, "weight": 4, "id": "e72"},
{"source": 29, "target": 33, "weight": 2, "id": "e73"},
{"source": 30, "target": 32, "weight": 3, "id": "e74"},
{"source": 30, "target": 33, "weight": 3, "id": "e75"},
{"source": 31, "target": 32, "weight": 4, "id": "e76"},
{"source": 31, "target": 33, "weight": 4, "id": "e77"},
{"source": 32, "target": 33, "weight": 5, "id": "e78"}
]
}
```

Comment: The line to set has a typo:

Comment: graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="edge_color", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1) NOT with "edge_attrs"

Comment: One way to solve this is to use the code from https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8183. I know this code work because I am using it on this same data. But as you can read the new way is to simplify the process of writing. May be my implementation is wrong.